# How to modify a local variable of one function from other function?

Tags: c

```
int main ()
{
    int a, b;

    call(&b);

    printf("%d, %d",a , b);    
}

void call(int *ptr)
{


}
```

Desired output:

```
50, 100
```

How to write the call function so as to modify both the variables to get the desired output??

Comment: So pass both variables into `call`.

Comment: @YuriyIvaskevych You meant the pointers to the variables, right?

Comment: This is why functions have parameters.

Comment: There is no scanf in the code hows it printing 50 100

Comment: How about `call(&a); call(&b);`, or `void call(int *pta, int *ptb)`

Comment: @SouravGhosh actually yes)

Comment: i can not modify the main function. i just have to write the called function.

Comment: thanks guys but i got the solution....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{

     int a,b;

     call(&b);

     printf("%d, %d\n", a,b);

}


int call(int *ptr)

{
    int  *m;

    m = ptr++;

    *ptr = 50;

    *m = 100;
}
```

Comment: This is essentially the same solution that I provided, and posted after mine too; but I was at great pains to emphasize that this invokes **undefined behavior**. I believe that anyone providing such an answer has a responsibility to point this out.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where the values `50` and `100` are coming from or exactly what you are asking but maybe this will help with your question.

Since C is pass by value you need to send pointers to actually change the value inside another function.

Since the `call` function will have pointer values you need to dereference the pointers before changing the value.

Here is an example:

```
void call(int *a, int *b)
{
    *a = 50;
    *b = 100;
}

int main()
{
    int a, b;

    call(&a, &b);

    printf("%d, %d\n", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While we are exploring the many ways this output could be achieved, consider that the function could store state in a static variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void call(int *ptr);

int main(void)
{
    int a, b;

    call(&a);
    call(&b);

    printf("%d, %d\n",a , b);
}

void call(int *ptr)
{
    static int store = 0;

    store += 50;
    *ptr = store;
}
```

Program output:

```
50, 100
```

Note that you may also be able to do this as follows, without any modifications to `main()`. But be warned that **this method invokes undefined behavior!** It is undefined behavior to write to a location past the end of an array object, and in the case of `a` and `b`, these are considered to be array objects of size 1. Here we are assuming that this write will work, and that `a` and `b` are stored next to each other in memory. We further assume that `a` has the higher address in memory.

I would say that you should never do this, but I can see no other way to modify `a` from the function `call()` without knowing the address of `a`. You have been warned.

```
void call(int *ptr)
{
    *ptr = 100;
    *(ptr + 1) = 50;
}
```

Comment: @user3639779-- I have added a method that allows you to do this without modifying `main()` in any way. But, be warned that it invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
void call(int *ptr)
{
    *ptr = 100;
}

int main ()
{
    int a, b;

    a = 50;
    call(&b);

    printf("%d, %d",a , b);    
}
```

See [demo](https://repl.it/F8rH/1)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this:

```
int main ()
{
    int a, b;    
    call(&a, &b);    
    printf("%d, %d",a , b);    
}

void call(int *ptr1, int *ptr2)
{
  *a = 50;
  *b = 100;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a local variable in function `a` by calling function `b` you have two options.

1) Let function `b` return a value that you assign to the variable in function `a`. Like:

```
int b() {return 42;}

void a()
{
    int x = b();
    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

This does, however, not seem to be what you are looking for.

2) Pass a pointer to the variable to function `b` and change the variable through that pointer

```
void b(int* p)  // Notice the * which means the function takes a pointer
                // to integer as argument
{
    *p = 42;    // Notice the * which means that 42 is assigned to the variable
                // that p points to
}

void a()
{
    int x;
    b(&x);      // Notice the & which means "address of x" and thereby
                // becomes a pointer to the integer x

    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```